# HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: service, asmx

I faced the issue the HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The remote server returned an error (403) forbidden.

My web config in window service is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DataSyncServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="DataSyncServiceSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BusinessServiceSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647"
            messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
            realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
          </httpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/AppService/BusinessService.asmx"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BusinessServiceSoap12"
    contract="BusinessServiceSoap12" name="BusinessServiceSoap12" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/SynchorizationService/DataSyncService.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DataSyncServiceSoap"
    contract="DataSyncServiceSoap" name="DataSyncServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

I also add mime type in IIS with full trust level in web.config. But still facing same issue on server